# In Xamarin, should I be worried about displaying a large content within a scrollview?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, scrollview

I'm fairly new to Xamarin. I have a grid with 3 columns and many rows (the number of rows is not limited to a specific number) filled with images. This grid is placed within a scrollview. The thing is, I'm worried that I'll face memory exceptions for excessive amounts of rows.

Is this a thing that I should be concerned about or does Xamarin handle it "automagically". If so how should I approach to this problem?
Note: I don't need all of the images loaded at the same time.

Comment: In your case it would  be better to use CollectionView . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Thank you for your answer. If I use this I shouldn't be worried about the memory, right?

Comment: Yes , I will post it as answer with more details , could you accept it ? Which will help more people :)

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT of course, could you up vote my question? Which will help more people :)

Comment: Allow me to upvote both of you

Comment: @Ayudh much appreciated :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to use CollectionView if you want to display large number of similar items .

**CollectionView** is a view for presenting lists of data using different layout specifications. It aims to provide a more flexible, and performant alternative to **ListView**.

- CollectionView has a flexible layout model, which allows data to be
  presented vertically or horizontally, in a list or a grid.
- CollectionView supports single and multiple selection.
- CollectionView has no concept of cells. Instead, a data template is
  used to define the appearance of each item of data in the list.

In your case , you just need to set the **ItemsLayout** as GridItemsLayout .

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding xxx}">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout ... />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        
    </CollectionView>
```

For more details you could check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout .